# Why am I getting a "cannot read properties of null reading ParentNode" error from vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my Vue project I'm using vue-router. When I navigate *away* from  a certain page I get a vague error and the router stops working. Clicking links updates the URL in the browser, but the app won't navigate to the respective pages.

The error is

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')

The page in question uses a watcher to update the route `query` parameters when the user changes filtering and sorting options. This way, when the page is refreshed/copied/bookmarked, the same options will be selected on their return.

```js
watch(
  () => route.query,
  () => {
    selectedAddresses.value = selectedAddressesQuery.value
    selectedStatuses.value = selectedStatusesQuery.value
    selectedSortOrder.value = selectedSortOrderQuery.value
  },
  { deep: true }
)

watch(
  () => [
    selectedAddresses.value,
    selectedStatuses.value,
    selectedSortOrder.value,
  ],
  async () => {
    router.replace({
      query: {
        ...route.query,
        address: selectedAddresses.value,
        sort: selectedSortORder.value,
        status: selectedStatuses.value,
      },
    })
  }
)
```

Why am I getting this error when I navigate away from the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was the watcher was being triggered when navigating away from the page because the query gets cleared, technically changing it.

The solution was to add a guard statement to the watch handler to check if we're still on the current page.

```js
watch(
  () => route.query,
  () => {
    // prevent triggering on page leave, which clears the query
    if (route.name !== 'invoices') return

    selectedAddresses.value = selectedAddressesQuery.value
    selectedStatuses.value = selectedStatusesQuery.value
    selectedSortOrder.value = selectedSortOrderQuery.value
  },
  { deep: true }
)
```

This prevents the second watcher (that watches those values being set) from being triggered, which was trying to update the route that is no longer there.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same question but, in my case I found the cause was `<Suspense>` where the slots for `#default` or `#fallback` presented a source containing more than one root element or just text.

> Dispite Vue3 allowing multiple root elements, components used for route views should still only have one root element

The following will cause such an error if presented in `#default` or `#fallback` slots:

```js
/** BAD: A lone string **/

<template #fallback>
  Loading...
</template>

/** GOOD: Wrapped in a single DIV **/

<template #fallback>
  <div>Loading...</div>
</template>
```

```js
/** BAD: More than one root element in a routed component **/

<template>

  <component :is="Compnent">
    <div>Line 1</div>
    <div>Line 2</div>
  </component>

</template>

/** GOOD: Single root element **/

<template>

  <component :is="Compnent">
    <div>
      <div>Line 1</div>
      <div>Line 2</div>
    </div>
  </component>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with `<Teleport>`.

The target ("to") node was not there (because of `v-if`) at the time when the page which has `<Teleport>` tried to render.

So, you could try to comment out `<Teleport>`s and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was due to a child component rendering because of a value in the store and in the async setup script of that child component, the store gets mutated to a value implying that the child component should not be rendered in the v-if.

`aStore.getter` returns true

```
<template>
  <ComponentA v-if="aStore.getter" />
  <ComponentB v-else />
</template>
```

Inside script setup of ComponentA

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const aStore = useStore()
await aStore.runAction() // afterwards, aStore.getter returns false
</script>
```